# ¿Es posible usar triggers en la misma tabla en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Mi problema es que tengo una tabla llamada students y quiero que se dispare un  trigger al momento que un nuevo student se registre, el trigger me realice un correo electrónico pero dentro de la misma tabla student obvio en otro campo de la misma tabla esto es posible?

Me genera el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com), si eres nuevo, realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), también te recomiendo, que visites [¿Cómo Preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para formular de manera correcta las preguntas, para que estas reciban respuesta; ademas de ser útiles para otras personas.

Comment: Te recomiendo, que el error que te genera, lo copies y lo pegues dentro de la pregunta como un `bloque de código`,  sino es sumamente difícil ayudarte!

Comment: No conozco en detalle como funciona MySQL, pero tienes que entender que si agregas un insert en el trigger  sobre la misma tabla, se volvería a ejecutar el trigger que volvería a hacer el insert que volvería, etc...  Explica un poco más en detalle lo que buscas, seguramente hay otra solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que hagas procedimiento almacenado para insertar y hacer inserciones, llamas el procedimiento y no la tabla. Algo así:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE correo(
    IN id_students INT (11),
    IN name VARCHAR(30),
    IN  firts_lastname VARCHAR(30),
    IN second_lastname VARCHAR(30))

BEGIN
declare correo varchar (100);
declare pass varchar (40);
set correo = concat(name,'.',first_lastname,'@ejemplo.com'));
set pass= ('12345seis');

insert into students
values(id_students,name,first_lastname, second_lastname,correo,pass);

END
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias colega esto es mucho mejor de lo que yo planeaba hacer

Answer (score 0):

Puede leer en la documentación lo siguiente (en inglés):

> [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Restrictions for Stored Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)
>
> ...
>
> - A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>     function or trigger.
>
> ...

Por ello, el disparador (trigger) no podrá realizar el `INSERT` sobre la misma tabla que lo invocó.

Un par de opciones:

Usando disparador (trigger):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `newemail` BEFORE INSERT ON `students`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.`newemail` := CONCAT(NEW.`name`, '_@hotmail.com');
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tUGZrfWPXjtSCEUMQwHoyh/0).

Usando columna generada (generated column): (MySQL >= 5.7.6 [13.1.18.8 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `students` (
  `id_student` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `first_lastname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `second_lastname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `newemail` VARCHAR(113) AS (CONCAT(`name`, '_@hotmail.com')) NOT NULL
);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rsxMkALcGc6c5GWocAx2mf/0).